# How to delete a key in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We all know that we have `get` and `set` in ember, but how do you `delete` a key in a emberjs object?

Assume an object looks like this

```
Ember.Object.create({
    conf: {
        name: 'John',
        age: 16
    }
});
```

During a data transport I would need to delete a key from `conf`, let's say `age`. How do you do that to correctly delete a key away from `conf`? I have tried `set('conf.age', null)` or `undefined` but seems like not working at all.

**EDIT**

A little bit of background. When I say it doesn't work for setting it undefined or null, it means it doesn't suits my need. My classes is automatically saving the `conf` data into a Mongo collection. So let's say now you have one key that is unused and you want to get rid of it, how do you remove it?

Take note that there is a bigger class governing the saving process/data validation and so extending the controller just to do the deletion doesn't fit too well (ugly). And there is this `beforeSave` action that the extended class can hook on to clean up unused keys, but the problem is just that how to remove this key?

It seems like such a simple action do not exist in ember, probably to deal with all sort of binding/observers..

Comment: When you say set('conf.age', undefined) not working at all, you mean theObject.get("conf.age") is returning 16 instead of undefined even after setting it to undefined ?

Comment: There is one reason for this. This `conf` is going to be saved into the db with some generic checking. I was hoping this `conf.age` will not be saved into the db. For now I was setting it to undefined, but it shows up as `conf.age: ''` in the db.

Comment: Why do you need to delete a key ? Basically when you POST to your server {name: 'John', age: undefined}, you can add a server side validation on params['age'] value if it is undefined do nothing, else modify the age to a newer one, or may be I did not understand your question properly? Or do you mean that you delete a key on the client side for a model and it should delete the respective attribute for the model on the server-side(mongo object) ?

Comment: Nah, I know it can be done on the server side (which is what I am doing it now) to get rid of this key. Just my question is how is it going to be done on client side if I want to get rid of it before submitting. Perhaps my example is not too well formatted and caused confusion. The original code covers over thousands of lines and comprises of many inheritance and extends so I thought it would be easy to just make it simple.

Answer (score 8):

if you set a property on an ember object:

```
this.set('myObject.keyA', [1,2,3]);
```

it will now keep track of that key

```
Ember.keys('myObject'); // will show ['keyA'];
```

you cannot delete a key by setting it to null

```
this.set('myObject.keyA', null);
```

since

```
Ember.keys('myObject'); // will STILL show ['keyA'];
```

instead simply delete it just as a javascript object

```
delete this.get('myObject').keyA;
```

then confirm the key is gone

```
Ember.keys('myObject'); // will show [] an empty array;
```

Comment: Thanks for digging this out! I wasn't on this project anymore so I doubt if I will need this. Upvote anyway for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply 'delete' the key (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) ? Assuming that your Ember object is named obj, I would do

```
delete obj.conf.age;
```

Comment: In fact that's just an example. The real thing is that my key is in controller. I need to delete a specific key from my view. So the syntax will be awkward to do, like `delete this.get('controller.conf').age`?? No way~

Comment: do you actually need to delete it or is hiding it based on a condition in your template an option?

Comment: The key must be removed to save space actually. It's not for presenting, but for saving. Perhaps I was wrong, but the idea is to get rid of this key instead of setting it undefined or empty.

Answer (score 0):

In fact u can define your own function to handle this like

```
Ember.Object.create({
    conf: {
        name: 'John',
        age: 16
    },
    deleteProp:function(key)
    {
       delete this.conf[key]
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't quite solve the issue as it will be awkward to extending the controller just to solve this. I will keep this as the final answer if no one has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @mihai answer:

If you wanna delete nested propery you could do something like this:

```
function deleteKeyFromPath([object, path]) {
  let propertyPathArray = path.split('.');

  if (propertyPathArray.length > 1) {
    let keyToDelete = propertyPathArray.pop();
    let parentPropertyPath = propertyPathArray.join('.');
    delete get(object, parentPropertyPath)[keyToDelete];
  } else {
    delete object[path];
  }
}

let user = {
email: 'johbdoe@gmail.com',
personalInfo: {
    name: 'Jack',
    address: {
        line1: 'westwish st',
        line2: 'washmasher',
        city: 'wallas',
        state: 'WX'
       }
   }
}
```

To delete 'name', `call deleteKeyFromPath([user, 'personalInfo.name'])`